# Уведомления для андроид приложения

Tags: java, c#, api, firebase, push-уведомления

Второй месяц занимаюсь выполнением тестового проекта, а именно простейшего мессенджера.

Что сделано:

1. написана серверная часть на C# (Web-Api-Asp.Net-Core) (в Visual Studio) - API-интерфейс. Методы сервиса принимают, обрабатывают, сохраняют в БД (SQL Server), считывают с БД, упаковывают и отправляют на клиент данные по потребности запросов.
2. Написано на JAVA (в Android Studio) простое приложение, коммуницирующее с выше указанным API-сервисом.

Мессенджер прекрасно работает (как я верил в это) и я с радостью наблюдал плоды своей работы: пользователи реально общались между собой в режиме реального времени.

Но препод не принял мою работу и дал срок максимум две недели переделать систему.

Суть проблемы: основная проблема - высоконагружаемость приложения из-за частого пинга сервера (раз в секунду клиент опрашивает вебсервис на наличие поступивших новых сообщений).
Дополнительная проблема - неполучение уведомлений с сервера в случае когда пользователь вышел из приложения.

Промониторив возможные варианты решения данных проблем наткнулся на такую систему как ФаерБейз.

Но не могу до конца понять механизм ее работы.
Если я правильно понимаю, то суть сводится к тому, что мой сервер (API-сервис) по мере надобности отправляет на сервер ФаерБейз определенные пакеты данных (и они там где-то складываются, или не складываются) и уже сервер ФаерБейз отправляет (рассылает) эти данные
по клиентским приложениям.

Клиент, получив подобное уведомление, кликает на него и переходит в соответствующую Активити приложения и далее уже само приложение отправляет запрос на мой API-сервис для получения всех полных новых актуальных данных.

Правильно ли я понимаю суть замысла сервиса ФаерБейз, или я путаю?

Прошу опытных помочь поскольку времени для реализации мало, а начинать разработку с неправильным пониманием сути решения не хочу.

Заранее спасибо за всякую помощь.

Comment: Если вы сделали "мессенджер" на простом Rest API, то мне вас жаль) Вместо того, чтобы подписаться на события, вы вынуждены теперь нагружать постоянно сервер вечным дерганием его данных, повторным подключением, и так далее. Обычно такое реализуют при помощи соккет соединения, которое раз устанавливается, а потом просто слушаются его события. В C# за него отвечает SignalR.

Comment: Да, именно так и происходит - сервер постоянно "дергается". За направление по SignalR благодарю!

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость, не могли бы Вы ткнуть на более-менее живой пример реализации SignalR?!

Comment: Этих примеров в интернете полно, странно, что не смогли найти нужное. Ну допустим [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/signalr/1.1.php). Что касается клиента - не скажу, я не Java разработчик.

Comment: Понаходил примеру, но они все о типе вебсайт-сервер. Мне надобно для вебприложения (андроид). Можно самому писать велосипед, но в андроид полно подводных камней. Времени в обрез.

Comment: Еще раз повторю, я не программист Java, как там реализовать грамотно, я вам не скажу. Единственное что могу, так это погуглить за вас, вот например [первая ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client) по запросу `SignalR Java`. "Свой велосипед" - почему бы и нет? Соккеты имеют +- одинаковую структуру, подключиться к ним в любом приложении без труда можно, главное иметь нормальный сервер.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за помощь! Благослови вас и ваших потомков Господь! Как реализую, поделюсь кодом.

Comment: Я решил свой вопрос именно через SignalR. Все оказалось намного проще. Общение клиента с сервером удалось настроить. Далее понять как разграничивать разных пользователей (по принадлежности к соответствующим чатам дабы не рассылать всем подряд сообщения от всех подряд), ну и изучить нюансы-детали в более правильной настройке всей этой системы.

Если кому интересно, могу поделиться наработками.

А если кто может подсказать как на сервере организовать распределение клиентов по связанным диалогам - тоже не откажусь от помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Вот к какому понимаю процесса взаимодействия абонентов-клиентов через общение с сервером я пришел (поправьте, если понимание неверное):

1. Первый абонент отправляет сообщение на сервер. Это делается через установленное веб-сокет соединение (или другой транспорт, поддерживаемый SignalR), используя API, предоставляемое SignalR.
2. Сервер принимает сообщение. После получения сообщения сервер обрабатывает его как нам требуется (упаковка и отправка в хранилище, у меня это БД СКЛ).
3. Сервер отправляет сообщение второму абоненту (склоняюсь, что этот 3-й пункт может предшествовать 2-му). Используя подсказанный Вами `SignalR`, сервер может отправить сообщение определенным клиентам (например, другому абоненту чата, или другим абонентам чата) или группам клиентов. Это делается асинхронно и, как я наблюдаю, практически мгновенно, поэтому второй абонент получает сообщение с минимальной задержкой.
4. Запись сообщения в базу данных. Для сохранения истории сообщений сервер может асинхронно записывать сообщения в базу данных. Это обеспечивает постоянство данных и позволяет абонентам восстановить историю сообщений при повторном подключении или просмотре истории. Смотрю в сторону асинхронности только по причине сохранения скорости доставки нового сообщения другому абоненту (абонентам) поскольку я так понимаю, на уровне взаимодействия с БД могут быть значительные потери времени. А если так, то теряется ощущение присутствия в реальном времени. А за это отсутствие ощущения я реально схлопочу неуд по предмету.
5. Процесс повторяется в обратном направлении, если второй абонент отправляет ответное сообщение первому абоненту.

Я так понимаю вместе с текстом сообщения следует передавать `userId` и `chatId`.
Если так, тогда на стороне сервера я, как мне кажется, мог бы отфильтровывать для определенного абонента только те сообщения, которые соотносятся с соответствующим чатом, проверяя на совпадение `chatId`.

Но пока я не "въезжаю" как это возможно реализовать на этапе ДО внесения сообщения в БД.

Если же вариант: сперва занести в БД новое сообщение, а потом выбрать новые сообщения для абонента на другом конце "связи" по значению `chatId`, тогда это понятно как делается.

Comment: Ответ не должен содержать новых вопросов. Если у вас есть дополнения к вопросу, удалите ответ и отредактируйте сам вопрос. Если появился новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, а в ответе оставьте только то что непосредственно отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать